# Finding out why Windows was unable to close

Tags: c++, windows, reboot

I have a C++ application which sometimes needs to restart Windows, we do this with ExitWindowsEx

```
if (!ExitWindowsEx(EWX_REBOOT | EWX_FORCE, SHTDN_REASON_MINOR_MAINTENANCE))
    return false;
```

The return value from ExitWindowsEx represents whether the parameters were understood and whether Windows successfully processed the shutdown request, but the shutdown itself is asynchronous and you cannot tell from the return value alone whether the reboot will actually work.

We have a situation where ExitWindowsEx always returns successfully but sometimes the reboot is failing, and we don't know why. Is there any way that I could  keep track of a reboot beyond calling this function, or query why it failed?

Thanks,

Bill.

Comment: The best solution would be to not base your logic on restarting the system...

Comment: Oh yeah I'll just tell my boss that we have to rewrite our entire codebase =P

Comment: Have you checked the EventViewer to see if is there a entry of "why the shutdown failed" ?